# Unit test a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing

I have written a wcf service that i want to unit test. I have added a simple reference from my testproject to my wcf project which is in the same solution

this is my simple test

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var client = new SMTService.SMTService();
        var result = client.GetAllServerDatabase();

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);

    }
```

However, when i run the unit test, i get an error that the specified named connection string was not found in the configuration file.

When i invoke the service method with the wcf test client , it works well.

What am i doing wrong in my unit test?

Comment: Add the correct lines for the connection to the app.config of the unit test project. You can copy them from the web.config probably.

Comment: Should i also copy files like global.asax ? why are they not found when running the service using the unit test?

Comment: Only certain project types use the global.asax, unit test project should not need them so no, no need to copy these. They are not found as they are sepperated in different projects (my guess), they both have their own configuration file, which points them to the right endpoints (ip address, port, service name etc.). If this is missing, the client (the unit test project) has no clue where it is, as it can't read the configuration file of the other project, eventhough they are in the same solution.

Comment: I moved the method calls that were in the global.asax to the constructor of my webservice and now it works fine. Thanx!

Comment: @jonasvermeulen please add the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted so that others know that this issue is resolved. Thanks.